# Analyzing the difference from 2 execution flows

Tags: bin-diffing

I'm a beginner in the reversing field, so apologize if the question is too dumb.

When analyzing binaries I always had this idea of saving somehow an execution flow so I can compare with other saved flow and get the exact points where they differ so I can start analyzing from that point.

Having a tool capable of doing that would be awesome. I can think of a lot of stuff I could do with this that with my current skill level is simply not feasible.

Is there a tool that already does that?

If not, how could I create such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there a marvelous tool available for your needs. Moreover it's free and open source (however earlier it was a commercial product - thanks to Google)

Also please do check their another product BinDiff for comparison/difference in code execution.

[Link to software: Zynamics - Bin Navi](https://www.zynamics.com/binnavi.html)

Comment: checking it rn. Thanks for the information!

Comment: hey friend I'm having a really hard time installing BinNavi. Do you know of any alternative or any place where I can find a tutorial on installing the app?

Comment: @underthevoid Hi, I understand it can be quite complex to build and install BinNavi from source code. However when it was a commercial product it was easy to install and as it was packaged in a installer. It's better to search for the older commercial release to get work done. I think you understood what I mean.